# How do you store data so when I restart the bot it doesn't reset

Tags: javascript, discord, bots, discord.js

I am working on an economy command but every time I restart the bot it resets the balance.
I don't know how to store data so can you help me

Also I am new to coding and coding a discord bot so can you please explain in baby steps

Here is my code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const fs = require("fs");
bot.on('message', async message => {
    if (message.content.startsWith("!bal")) {
        let user = message.mentions.users.first() || message.author
        let money = db.fetch(`money_${user.id}`)
        if (money === null) money = 0

        message.channel.send(`${user} you have ${money} coins`)
    }
    let timeout = 86400000
    let amount = 1000
    if (message.content === "!daily") {
        let daily = await db.fetch(`daily_${message.author.id}`);
        if (daily != null && timeout - (Date.now() - daily) > 0) {
            let time = ss(timeout - (Date.now() - daily));
            message.channel.send(`You already collected your daily reward, you can come back in **${time.hours}h ${time.minutes}m ${time.seconds}s**`)
        }else {
            embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setAuthor(`Daily`, message.author.displayAvatarURL)
            .setColor("GREEN")
            .setDescription(`**Daily Rewards**`)
            .addField('Collected', amount)
            message.channel.send(embed)
            db.add(`money_${message.author.id}`, amount)
            db.add(`daily_${message.author.id}`, Date.now())
        }
    }
    let timeoutworked = 3600000
    let worked = await db.fetch(`worked_${message.author.id}`)
    if (message.content === "!work"){
        if (worked != null && timeoutworked - (Date.now() - worked) > 0) {
            let time = ss(timeout - (Date.now() - worked));
            message.channel.send(`You have already worked, please come back in **${time.hours} ${time.minutes}m ${time.seconds}s**`)
    }else{
        let amountearned = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000) + 1
        let jobs = ["Developer", "Chef", "Doctor", "Cashier"]
        let job = jobs[Math.floor(Math.random() * jobs.length)]

        let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setAuthor(`${message.author.tag}, it payed off`, message.author.displayAvatarURL())
        .setDescription(`${message.author.tag}, you worked as a ${job} and earned ${amountearned} coins`)
        message.channel.send(embed)
        db.add(`money_${message.author.id}`, amountearned)
        db.set(`worked_${message.author.id}`, Date.now())
    }
}})
```

Also I use Heroku to host my bot

Answer (score 0):

you can use local Storage to store data in the browser

```js
//Store data in LocalStorage
localStorage.setItem("title", "Hello World");             // (Key / Value)

//Get data
console.log(localStorage.getItem("title"));

//Set Objects
var user= {
    nombre: "Ava",
    apellido: "Lovelace",
    edad: 28
};
localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(user));     // (Key / Value)

//Get Objeto
var userJS = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"));
console.log(userJS);

//Remove item
localStorage.removeItem("user");

//Clean all localStorage
localStorage.clear();
```

Remember you can only store string data type in localStorage, so you can use JSON.stringify(obj) to convert object to string, and JSON.parse(str) to convert json string to object.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like force refresh of the db is enabled, i.e, drop all the existing tables and create new tables at each reboot of the bot. Check the code where you're defining the schema and creating the db.

For example, in sequelize you do the following to define a schema and create the table:

```
var User = sequelize.define('user',{
    // schema
});

User.sync({force: true}); // creating the table
```

Note how {force: true} is passed while creating the table. This tells sequelize to drop existing tables with that name and create new one every time that code is executed.

I used sequelize as an example partly because you didn't mention what db you are using and partly because I use sequelize. Check for any documentation for such behavior in the db you are using.

Edit:

Quick.db is a persistent db and I didn't find any evidence of force refresh of db each time you run the code. By all means, it should be persistent.

So the problem is probably heroku's ephemeral filesystem. They outright suggest not to use file based databases like sqlite3 [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3) and [here](https://help.heroku.com/K1PPS2WM/why-are-my-file-uploads-missing-deleted). Apparently every 24 hours or so, all files in the project directory are replaced with those from the latest deploy.

The solution is to use the [postgresql](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/heroku-postgresql) addon which is free for limited usage.

That's all I could find. Hope it helps.

Comment: I use quick.db pls help